# Conditionally retry iterations in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, loops

I have problems achieving the following in Python. I am making API requests in a for loop, and would like to implement a status code check and a pause based on the status code, to make sure that the code will run without errors. So for example, I am after something like:

```
for i in X:
    url = 'abc' + i
    r = requests.get(url)
    while r.status_code = 123: 
        sleep(1)
        r = requests.get(url)
    <the code I want to run that uses r>
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? Except that `=` should be `==`, otherwise it's probably a syntax error.

Comment: It runs forever.

Comment: Could the problem be with the request which always fails?

Comment: No, I checked that. The request is OK (200) after the sleep step. Just looks like the for loop runs all over again. But that does not happen if I remove the while loop.

Comment: I doubt that the problem is demonstrated by the code you posted. It may be in the difference between the posted code and your actual code. Can you try writing a reproducible, self-contained example? You could use a public URL for testing, remove the outer loop etc.

Comment: Can you add more details in the question, also what is status code `123` ?

Comment: You are all correct. Something else in the code was causing the problem, but the behavior really tricked me into believing that the while loop was broken. Sorry for the confusion/badly formulated question.